# Is there any connector application between hibernate search and apache solr?

Tags: java, apache, hibernate, search, solr

I need to integrate hibernate search with apache solr.Is there any connector application to do that.

Comment: Please edit question and elaborate, show some code (link is not enough, it can disappear, so the question becomes useless)

Comment: I just want to know is there any connector application for hibernate search and apache solr. I don't have any code to put here.

Comment: Okay, then I'm afraid your question doesn't fit here and should be closed... See point 4 : http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic